# Find Packet Loss and Trace Route in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to code to capture the packet loss on computers, but the only way I've been able to do so was to run the NetStat.exe and the TraceRt.exe processes and capture them to a listbox (using the code below):

```
Private Sub myProcess()
    Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim theFile, sTemp, sLineOut, mySent, myRetrans As String
    Dim intSentStart As Double
    Dim isEnabled As Boolean

    p = New System.Diagnostics.Process
    theFile = t.Name

    If File.Exists("c:\windows\system32\" & theFile) Then
        theFile = "c:\windows\system32\" & theFile
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to find the " & theFile & " file on your computer.", "File Find Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    Select Case t.Name
        Case "TraceRt.exe"
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-h 30 www.stackoverflow.com"

        Case "NetStat.exe"
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-s -p tcp"
    End Select

    Try
        p.StartInfo.FileName = theFile
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.Start()
        p.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal

        sLineOut = ""

        Do While Not p.HasExited
            sTemp = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
            If sTemp <> "" Then
                sLineOut = sLineOut & sTemp & vbNewLine
                'Send to listbox
                setTrace(sTemp)
            End If
        Loop
        If sLineOut = "" Then
            'Clear Listbox
            clearTrace()
            myProcess()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If t.Name = "NetStat.exe" Then
            Try
                If lboxTrace.Items.Count < 9 Then
                    'Clear Listbox
                    clearTrace()
                    myProcess()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                mySent = ""
                mySent = lboxTrace.Items.Item(8) '("Segments Sent")
                mySent = Trim(mySent.Replace("Segments Sent", ""))
                mySent = Trim(mySent.Replace("=", ""))

                myRetrans = ""
                myRetrans = lboxTrace.Items.Item(9)
                myRetrans = Trim(myRetrans.Replace("Segments Retransmitted", ""))
                myRetrans = Trim(myRetrans.Replace("=", ""))

                intSentStart = Math.Round((myRetrans / mySent) * 100, 2)

                'setTrace sends data to the listbox
                If intSentStart < 2 Then
                    setTrace("Your Current Packet Loss is: " & intSentStart & "%.")
                    setTrace("Your packet loss is within acceptable ranges.")
                Else
                    setTrace("Your Current Packet Loss is: " & intSentStart & "%.")
                    setTrace("Your packet loss is below acceptable ranges!")
                    setTrace("Please contact your Internet Provider about your Internet Connection.")
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'Clear Listbox
                clearTrace()
                myProcess()
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Does anyone have a better idea to get this information?  I'd rather use managed code instead of hacking through it this way.

Thanks in Advance!
-JFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you taken a look at the [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)?

Edit: Actually for TraceRoute, take a look at the answers here: [TraceRoute and Ping in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142614/traceroute-and-ping-in-c).

For Netstat, take a look at http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/netstat-in-c/.