# TCP Traceroute in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, traceroute

How can you perform a TCP traceroute in C#? Is it even possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142614/traceroute-and-ping-in-c

Comment: they seem to all be using ICMP. I need one using TCP packets.

Comment: What's a "TCP traceroute": which TCP socket would you hope to connect to on each host along the route? Traceroute is implemented using ICMP, not TCP.

Comment: I'm guessing that they're looking to create a tool like hping?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcptraceroute
http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/
http://tracetcp.sourceforge.net/

not trying to do hping, just a traceroute that relies on HTTP, wanted to see if is possible in C# without having to use some sort of packet sniffer/driver like pcap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need raw ethernet frames to generate TCP packets by hand as Windows won't let you send TCP packets over raw sockets.

See how nmap gets raw ethernet frames. Repeat it.

Comment: can i use this? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx
he seems to have implemented a network sniffer using C#

Comment: No sorry. You can read all you want that way but your outbound TCP packets never reach the wire.

Comment: I was reading a little bit on this and it seems like it was a windows XP SP2 fix that caused the raw packet limitation - what if my application is targeting windows server 2008? is this limit there too?

Comment: Sorry, but it's been there in every Windows version since.

Comment: see the answer below, you cant still do tcp frames over raw packet on windows server 2008

Comment: Huh. They didn't put it into the server versions.

Answer (score 1):

From MSFT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(VS.85).aspx

On Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista, and Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:

- TCP data cannot be sent over raw
  sockets.
- UDP datagrams with an invalid source
  address cannot be sent over raw
  sockets. The IP source address for
  any outgoing UDP datagram must exist
  on a network interface or the
  datagram is dropped. This change was
  made to limit the ability of
  malicious code to create distributed
  denial-of-service attacks and limits
  the ability to send spoofed packets
  (TCP/IP packets with a forged source
  IP address).
- A call to the bind function with a
  raw socket is not allowed.

**These above restrictions do not apply to Windows Server 2008 , Windows Server 2003, or to versions of the operating system earlier than Windows XP with SP2.**