# How to get Local Router Address[Not IPV4 address of device] in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, system.net

I have tried below code but it keeps on giving the me iPhone(ie.Device) IP Address. But I want to get a **ROUTER IP ADDRESS**

```
public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        String ipAddress = "";

        foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(netInterface);
            if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
                netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
            {
                foreach (var addrInfo in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (addrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        ipAddress = addrInfo.Address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

> iPhone IPAddress: 192.168.0.19
> Router: 192.168.0.1

[image: Wifi address config screen]

I can do the Hacky way of removing the '9' from the last set of IP address. But I don't want to do this.

Comment: I assume that is just Apple's terminology for "Gateway"?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634868/get-the-default-gateway)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama from iOS Side it works well. thanks for that. but from Android side. it throws an error: ```type=1400 audit(0.0:400): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/8503/net/route" dev="proc" ino=4026532048 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c151,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.drawrect.tryrebex```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get a **ROUTER IP ADDRESS**(Gateway address) from Android side.

Create a DependenceService in Forms folder.

```
public interface INetServices  
{  
    string ConvertGateway();  
}
```

Then achieve this interface in the android folder.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NetService))]  
   namespace Forms.Droid  
   {  
       class NetService: INetServices  
       {  
           [Obsolete]
           public string ConvertGateway()  
           {  
               WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Service.WifiService);  
               int ip = wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.IpAddress;  
               int gateway = wifiManager.DhcpInfo.Gateway;

               IPAddress ipAddr = new IPAddress(ip);  
               IPAddress gatewayAddr = new IPAddress(gateway);
              
              
               return gatewayAddr.ToString();  
           }  
       }  
   }
```

And add following permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

In the Xamarin forms, you can get **ROUTER IP ADDRESS** like following code.

```
var gatewayAddress = DependencyService.Get<INetServices>().ConvertGateway();            
Console.WriteLine(gatewayAddress);
```

Comment: It is giving `10.0.2.2` not real one ie(192.168.0.1)

Comment: @iTag When it's connected to WiFi, I tested the code in my Android phone, and it returns the real one (Gateway: 172.20.10.1) , IP Address: 172.20.10.1  What does `10.0.2.2` represent in your mobile phone? Or meaningless?

Comment: I have tested with Android Emulator and it connected to Wifi router. not on Real device.

Comment: i am getting the same 10.0.2.2 and it throws and some warning as well. i will check real device as well. `type=1400 audit(0.0:18): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/3832/net/route" dev="proc" ino=4026532048 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c151,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_net:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.drawrect.tryrebex
`

Comment: @iTag I also think you should test it on the real machine. The same error reported twice is probably the reason for the Android Emulator.

Comment: Your code works well. i have tested with real device. i got the router gateway ip address.