# ASP.NET traceroute

Tags: c#, asp.net, ping, traceroute

This drives me crazy been searching and testing the whole day. I need a simple traceroute in c#. Ive been through all the major websites but i dont get how to list all the hops!

```
string hostName = "google.se";
Ping ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send(hostName);

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    Response.Write ("Address: " + reply.Address.ToString() + "<br>");
    Response.Write ("RoundTrip time: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "<br>");
    Response.Write ("Time to live: " + reply.Options.Ttl + "<br>");
    Response.Write ("Don't fragment: " + reply.Options.DontFragment + "<br>");
    Response.Write ("Buffer size: " + reply.Buffer.Length + "<br>");
}
else
{
    Response.Write (reply.Status);
}
```

.

EDIT: the q you posted as duplicate is the one ive been sitting with for the last five hours, and cant figure out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TraceRoute and Ping in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142614/traceroute-and-ping-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Only some versions of Ping return the tracerout.  I opened a cmd.exe and typed ping/? and the help results indicated the -k option in my ping will return the traceroute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142614/traceroute-and-ping-in-c-sharp

Comment: An answer on the indicated duplicate question has the code for a traceroute implementation. You just need to copy and paste that into a C# file and compile, then you'd be able to do `Answer.TraceRoute.GetTraceRoute(hostName)`. What's the part you can't figure out?

Comment: Ah thank you! I was so close. But how do i print the results?

Comment: Ok i got it to print :D how do i gracefully add millisec and hostname? Btw ill give you a thumbsup if you make your Response as an answer!

Comment: https://github.com/bencorn/traceroute/tree/master