# Can I trace a call made by visitors in a web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, traceroute

For my web application I want to increase the security a bit by checking the route that a visitor has made to get at my server. Now, there is various information already available on how to do a traceroute where you'd just generate an outgoing request for the IP address. ([This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142614/traceroute-and-ping-in-c-sharp), for example.) But I don't want that!
What I want is that I get an incoming request and I want to know the route that this specific request has taken! I don't want the route to the visitor but the route of the request. And I'm not sure if this information can even be retrieved in some way...
Is this possible? If so, how? In C#, of course...

Comment: The route of the request would go back to the visitor - where else would you expect it to end? What specific goal are you trying to achieve? How will this *increase security*? How does knowing what route this comment is taking to get to StackOverflow to this page improve security? Knowing where it originated (my IP address) improves security, but how does knowing what hops it went through to get to where you can read this?

Comment: I've noticed several suspicious requests to my server in recent times from different IP addresses. If they all share parts of their routes then it's likely that they're from the same hacker. I can then block access to visitors who use that specific route. (Well, just give them a 404 instead of content.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: "NO"
See [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)

The request may have been fragmented, different packets taking different routes to reach you, and the return path may well be different.  That's the beauty of IP and without it the packet would grow in size as it traversed the network.