# How to do a traceroute request through a HttpClient with a proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient, traceroute

Well, I want to test that the proxy is really working as it should and I would like to do a traceroute.

The only way I have found is by using the `Ping` class, with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45565253/3286975

Actually, I'm using TorSharp and I would like to now how it works. It uses the `HttpClient` class as you can see in this example: https://github.com/joelverhagen/TorSharp#example

So I have been looking for how to do a traceroute request using a similar approach for the `HttpClient` class, but haven't found anything.

Does anyone know where can I research more information? Can anybody guide me?

Comment: traceroute uses ICMP packets. Http uses TCP packets. They're different protocols.

Comment: Mmm... Thanks @canton7 I didn't know that fact. So there isn't any real way to do traceroute or something where I can see the hops that IP do over a HttpClient?

Comment: What proxy are you using? Nginx? Do you have control over it? If so, why not add a custom header on proxy and check if it exists on client?

Comment: I'm connecting through internet using a Proxy given by a Tor wrapper (TorSharp) (linked in question). So I would like to test this connection. @gmazoni

Comment: I see, if you have control of the proxy, I suggest to add headers, that depends in what kind of analisys you want to make. There are network tools to sniff the packets and give further data, like: PRTG Network Monitor. Take a look on  HTTP 3** codes too.

Comment: I saw that there are approaches using Sockets over TCP, but I don't know if there is any way to handle this with Http...

Comment: I feel like you asked "how can I converse with a spanish speaker using english?" and people keep responding, "you can't. speak spanish." and you keep asking how to do it with english. You either have to change your objective or use a compatible tool. It's either a traceroute (which uses ICMP) or a completely different thing that uses HTTP. What's your actual goal? Is your ultimate goal to converse with the spanish speaker or to speak in english? Likewise, is your goal to do a traceroute or to use HTTP?